# COM / .Net interoperability: tlbexp prefixes conflicted names with 'namespace_', how to workaround?

Tags: c#, com, interop

I want to implement a .Net wrapper around a Com Coclass (defined in a C++ dll), that has the exact same name and interface name as the COM object, but within in a different namespace. When I try to do that, I find that tlbexp adds a prefix to the name of the class (the exported type becomes namespace.namespace_classname). This is annoying because then the tlb file cannot be used easily in VBA for instance.

Here is an example to make things clearer

The C++ code is something like:

```
namespace CPP
{
    public interface IComObjectTest
    { ... }
    public class ComObjectTest : IComObjectTest
    { ... }
}
```

The C# code is something like:

```
namespace CS
{
    public interface IComObjectTest : CPP.IComObjectTest
    { 
         ...
    }

    public class ComObjectTest : CS.IComObjectTest
    {
         private CPP.ComObjectTest _test;
         public ComObjectTest(CPP.ComObjectTest test) { _test = test; }

         public CPP.ComObjectTest GetComObjectTest { get { return _test; } }

         ...
    }
}
```

When I compile the C# project and run tlbexp.exe on it. I get the following types exported:

```
CS.CS_ComObjectTest
CS.CS_IComObjectTest
```

while I would like to see:

```
CS.ComObjectTest
CS.IComObjectTest
```

Is this a limitation that can be overcome?
Any help appreciated,
Thanks